# dirty state of a DataGridViewComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Does DataGridViewComboBox have a dirty state? comparatively studying, datagridviewcheckbox has a dirty state.

thanks

Comment: Never heard about it. What is the 'dirty state' of the DataGridViewCheckBox control?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: The dirty state of the data grid view row/cell is some thing like -A cell is marked as modified if its contents have changed but the change has not been saved.

Comment: @Ramashankar Thank you! It's a great thing to learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if understand your question correctly. Dirty state is not limited to checkbox or combo box.

> A cell is marked as modified if its contents have changed but the
>   change has not been saved.

So if you are expecting an **CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged** event on combo box value changed then you should try calling

```
datagridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
```

Calling this on a newly entered brand will force the row to return true for IsCurrentRowDirty() method.

See [DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty() not set with editable DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979905/datagridview-iscurrentrowdirty-not-set-with-editable-datagridviewcomboboxcolum)

Comment: so when think about "modifiable" controls, there is only two a checkbox and a Textbox. so if there is dirty state for a cell it has to contain a modifiable control in it such as a textbox or checkbox and cells with any other controls such as Comboxbox, buttons, linklables and images are not modifiable thus those cell don't have a dirty state?